# Holomorphic function on the open unit disc with $|f(z)|\geq 1$ on disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the open unit disc $\mathcal{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\ 
|\ |z|<1\}$. Suppose that $$|f|\geq 1\ \ \text{on}\ \ \mathcal{D}\ \  \text{and}\ \ f(0)=i.$$ Which of the following are  possible values of $f\big(\frac{1}{2}\big).$

1. $-i$
2. $i$
3. $1$
4. $-1$

It is easy to see that option 2 is correct as $f(z)=i$. How to look for the other options?

Comment: 2 is correct because of $f(z)=i$, not because $f(z)=z$

Comment: Yes sorry for the typo. I am editing it.

Comment: Recall [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) or the [minimum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle#Minimum_modulus_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=\frac  1f$. Then $|g|$ attains its maximum at $0$ so it is a constant by MMP (Maximum  Modulus Principle). Hence $f(z)=i$ for all $z$.